# Unity play your project live in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

i want to make a game in Android using Unity. So i already used detect touch method, the thing is i have to back-forth from my laptop to my phone to try my game. Now i have a bug, which i want to debug.log to check the bug but i can't see the message on my phone
So is there any kind of plugin or way for me to play my game live while i could see my error message on unity at the same time? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Unity Remote 4** to play the game in unity and automatic stream the game to the phone.

It's also much faster because you don't need build the game and deploy on your phone. It also detects touches, gyroscope, accelerometer and camera.

All you need is download **Unity Remote 4** in play store, connect your phone via USB, active the debug mode in developers options on the phone, select your device in unity, and press play.

You can find more detailed info in the docs:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote4.html